# Highcharts arearange graph not respecting “connectEnds” option

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I’m trying to make a radial arearange graph that has a gap between the two ends, but no matter how I set the option it always renders a connection between the beginning and end.

connectEnds: true behaves as expected:
[image: connectEnds: true behaves as expected]

...but if you set it to false, it always renders a weird glitch in between the two ends:
[image: connectEnds: false always renders a weird glitch in between the two ends]

[Here’s a link to the JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd1s37wz/)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'arearange',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'connectEnds: false'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
        [1, 29.9, 111.5],
        [2, 106.4, 129.2],
        [3, 144.0, 176.0],
        [4, 135.6, 148.5],
        [5, 116.4, 194.1],
        [6, 116, 200],
        ],
        connectEnds: false,
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing this issue. I reported it as a bug on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread.

Link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13789

If you need the temporary workaround please ask for it in the comment - the core developers should respond to you immediately.

Comment: Thanks so much! I would appreciate the temporary workaround, if there is one—right now I’ve just been setting all null data to 0, which is less than ideal.